# Approximating formal surfaces by analytic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, formal-schemes

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve contained in a smooth projective $3$-fold (everything defined over $\mathbb C$). Let $\widehat X$ be the formal completion of $X$ along $C$ and suppose there exists a smooth surface $\widehat S \subset \widehat X$ containing $C$.

> **Question.** I would like to know if there exists an analytic neighbourhood $U \subset X$ containing $C$ and a **smooth** analytic surface in $U$ which
>   coincides with $\widehat S$ up to first order.  Of course, an algebraic surface $S$, smooth along $C$, with the same the property
>   would be even better.

If $C^2>0$ (self-intersection in $\widehat S$) then $\widehat S$ is automatically the restriction of a projective surface to $\widehat X$ thanks to results by Hironaka/Hartshorne. I am interested in the case where $C^2=0$.